# htaccess fails to allow domain access to sub-directory

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I have a sub-directory on a site with a zip file in it. I want to limit access to the zip file to certain domains. I have tried many methods but none are working. Below shows what I've tried where example.com is the calling site. I only tried one of these methods at a time but they all return a 403 result. I see many posts here about problems like this and the results are always that they work so I must be missing something. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Method 1

```
    SetEnvIf Referer "^example\.com/" goodsites
     
    order Deny,Allow 
    Deny from all 
    Allow from env=goodsites
```

Method 2

```
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from example.com
```

Method 3

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)*example\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
```

I added the following and it seems to do what I want.

```
    <FilesMatch "\.(zip|exe)$">
       Order Deny,Allow
       Deny from all
    </FilesMatch>
```

Comment: "example.com is the calling site" - Do you mean that there is an anchor/link to the zip file on `example.com` (ie. the referrer)? What version of Apache are you using?

Comment: The calling site runs a script that tries to download the zip file via curl. The server (both is this case) is using apache 2.4.

Comment: Do you have control over the calling script?

Comment: Yes, they are both my sites and are on different servers, if that matters.

Comment: _"The calling site runs a script that tries to download the zip file via curl."_ - and does that request send a referrer? If not, the first attempt is pointless. Third attempt, also pointless - HTTP_HOST is the machine the request is made _to_, not where it's made from. Have you tried method #2 with an IP address instead of domain name?

Comment: I tried adding the referer command to curl but it didn't help. I tried a different approach and added the code I show in my updated code. I've tested it a number of ways and it seems to work. I appreciate the attempts to help.

Comment: The code in your update "should" be blocking your CURL request as well??

Comment: I thought that would be the case when I first tried it but it doesn't for some reason. If I try to download it from the url directly it does stop that so it seems to be working as I want.